# If I put the redirect code after Timer.start, redirect won't work, trying to understand why order matters here

Tags: c#, redirect, timer, process

folks
Because of project requirement, I need create a child process (powershell.exe) and capture its stdout, and stderr, and output them to files c:\logs\test.log and c:\logs\error.log.  Below is the code for TestRedirect, it works great by calling it only.  However I find that if I call TestRedirect() before Timer.start, it works fine, but if I put it after Timer.start(), it call create the child process without problem, but redirect not work anymore.  Does anyone know why order matters here, how to fix it?

```
     public void TestRedirect()
    {
        Logger.LogContent("service starts.");

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SA = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        SA.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(SA);
        SA.bInheritHandle = true;
        GCHandle saHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(SA);
        IntPtr saPtr = (IntPtr)saHandle;

        uint flags = 0x80;
        SafeFileHandle outputFileHandle = NativeMethods.CreateFile(
            @"c:\logs\test.log",
            NativeMethods.GENERIC_WRITE,
            NativeMethods.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            saPtr,
            NativeMethods.OPEN_ALWAYS,
            flags,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        SafeFileHandle errorFileHandle = NativeMethods.CreateFile(
          @"c:\logs\error.log",
          NativeMethods.GENERIC_WRITE | NativeMethods.GENERIC_READ,
          NativeMethods.FILE_SHARE_READ | NativeMethods.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
          saPtr,
          NativeMethods.OPEN_ALWAYS,
          flags,
          IntPtr.Zero);


        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = (int)Marshal.SizeOf(si);
        si.dwFlags = NativeMethods.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        si.hStdOutput = outputFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
        si.hStdError = errorFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

        // flags that specify the priority and creation method of the process
        int dwCreationFlags = NativeMethods.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | NativeMethods.CREATE_NO_WINDOW;

        //string cmdLine = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "powershell.exe -executionPolicy bypass -file " + "\"" + scriptFilePath + "\" 1>\"" + resultFilePath + "\" 2>" + "\"" + errorFilePath + "\"");
        string cmdLine = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "powershell.exe -executionPolicy bypass -file \"c:\\test.ps1\"");

        IntPtr userToken;
        NativeMethods.WTSQueryUserToken(1, out userToken);
        PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

        // create a new process in the current user's logon session
        bool result = NativeMethods.CreateProcessAsUser(
                                        userToken,        // client's access token
                                        null,                   // file to execute
                                        cmdLine,        // command line
                                        ref SA,                 // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                        ref SA,                 // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                        true,                  // handles are not inheritable
                                        dwCreationFlags,        // creation flags
                                        IntPtr.Zero,            // pointer to new environment block 
                                        null,                   // name of current directory 
                                        ref si,                 // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                                        out procInfo);

        if (result == false)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine("failed to create process as user. Error code = {0}", errorCode);
            throw new Win32Exception("Failed to create process as user.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create process as user successfully.");
            Console.WriteLine("process id = " + procInfo.dwProcessId);
            Logger.LogContent("Create process as user successfully, process id = " + procInfo.dwProcessId);
        }

        NativeMethods.WaitForSingleObject(procInfo.hProcess, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(procInfo.hThread);
        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(procInfo.hProcess);
        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(outputFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(errorFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
    }
```

**This works.**

```
 TestRedirect();
        // Set up a timer to trigger every minute.
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 10000; // 60 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer.Start();
```

**This does not work**

```
            // Set up a timer to trigger every minute.
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 10000; // 60 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer.Start();
        TestRedirect();  // <---- not work for redirect, file is empty
```

Comment: Is there anyone knowing if Timer init will override something behind the scene?  Thanks